# Android icons: what does the term optical square mean?

Tags: android, push-notification, icons, android-push-notification

I'm looking for the sizes of the icons that I should provide to my **Android application** and I have read several times **the term of "optical square"** but I'm not sure to understand what it means.

Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optical square is the area of the icon where actual design of the icon is present. For example consider the below icon:

[image]

In it 32x32 dp is the full icon asset size, however the **optical square is only 24x24 dp**.

The full icon asset size is the total touch enabled area of the icon, the optical square includes only the focal area. It is considered as a best practice for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, thus everything outside the optical square will be (or could be?) truncated?

Comment: @Simon No, not necessarily. The concept of optical sqaure/focal area is to have an increased touch-enabled/actionable space around an icon. So, user's touches get registered easily without compromising on the visual aspects (e.g. having a too big icon)